# Counter for each item in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement a counter for each of the elements in an array and display them on the screen. I have an array and I want to display the following for each of the elements: name of the car, likes, increase button, and decrease button. When I tried to increase and decrease the likes, all the elements gets increase and decrease the same way. How do I keep the likes independent from each other and not share the same likes? For example, when I like one car, I want only that one to increase the `likes` count. Can someone assist me with this problem? This is my current code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Cars extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        likes: 0
    };

    this.incFav = this.incFav.bind(this);
    this.decFav = this.decFav.bind(this);
  }

  incFav(e) {
    this.setState({likes: this.state.likes + 1});
  }

  decFav(e) {
    this.setState({likes: this.state.likes - 1});
  }

  render() {
    //Passed this.props.cars from another component. It is an array of cars.
    const { cars } = this.props;
    return (
        <div>
            {cars.map((car, key) => {
                <li key={car}>
                    {car}
                    {this.state.likes}
                    <button onClick={this.incFav}>+</button>
                    <button onClick={this.decFav}>-</button>
                </li>
            })}
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Cars;
```

Answer (score 2):

Alright, the answer is pretty straightforward. You are confusing the state of your list of cars with the state of each individual car. In this case you have a state for the component `Cars`, but not for each specific car. My suggestion is to create an additional component called `Car`, that has its own `likes`. Your code would look something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Car from '../Car/Car.js';

const Cars = ({ cars }) => (
  <ul>{cars.map((car, key) => <Car car={car} key={car} />}</ul>
);

export default Cars;
```

As you notice the Cars list does not need to have any info about the state of each single car, that's something you would handle inside each Car component like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Car extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { likes: 0 };
    this.incFav = this.incFav.bind(this);
    this.decFav = this.decFav.bind(this);
  }

  incFav() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ likes: prevState.likes + 1 }));
  }

  decFav() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ likes: prevState.likes - 1 }));
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <li>
        {this.props.car}
        {this.state.likes}
        <button onClick={this.incFav}>+</button>
        <button onClick={this.decFav}>-</button>
      </li>
    );
  }
}

export default Car;
```

As you may notice there is really not need in this scenario for a `Cars` component so you can just embed this list in whichever part of your App directly, it's up to you. But having a separate component for each Car will guarantee you that they will have each a separate state with a separate counter for likes. Previously it was shared between all of them, make sure you understand why your code was not behaving as expected.

Comment: That makes sense then. I noticed that you in your approach for `incFav()` and `decFav()` methods, you used a callback function instead of doing `likes: this.state.likes + 1` and `likes: this.state.likes - 1` respectively. Is there a difference between using a callback and my initial approach?

Comment: I use it as a habit now if my future state depends on the older state, this approach guarantees that `prevState` is up to date and that I don't get an older state (which could cause weird states updates in certain scenarios). In your specific case you should be fine, but I would recommend to get into the habit of updating the state as shown IF the new state depends on the most up to date state.

Comment: For smaller app, you could technically be fine with a single component which contains state for each item by mapping it to some id, name.